# Is there a way to let constants only run once in a function in React?

Tags: reactjs, antd

**My problem:**

Currently, I'm trying to develop an exam/quiz mode for my web app using React and AntDesign. My problem is: When I click on the "test" button to submit the quiz. The entire function, including the constants and questions, reload. This generates entirely new questions and answers and results in me not being able to check the submitted answers with the correct answers.

This is the part, that should only run once:

```
        // Generates ten random questions from inputted JSON file
        const array = []
        for (let i = 1; i <= question.length; i++) {
        array.push(i)
        }
        const result = [];

        for (let j = 1; j <= 10; j++) {
        const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (question.length - j));
        result.push(array[random]);
        array[random] = array[question.length - j];
        }

        // Random shuffles the answers of the questions
        const answerarray = []
        for (let k = 1; k <= 4; k++) {
            answerarray.push(k)
        }
        const answerresult = [];

        for (let l = 1; l <= 4; l++) {
            const arandom = Math.floor(Math.random() * (4 - l));
            answerresult.push(answerarray[arandom]);
            answerarray[arandom] = answerarray[4 - l];
        }
```

**What I have tried:**

- I have tried using the Hooks `useMemo()` and `useEffect()` to no avail. This results in the "Cannot read the properties of undefined" error.
- I also tried isolating some parts of the `DisplayQuestions.js` file (see the link to CodeSandbox). This resulted in the "test" button not working because of the `<Form>` component that AntD uses. (It has to be in one file.)

**Link to CodeSanbox:**
https://codesandbox.io/s/problem-wym5m?file=/src/App.js

I hope someone can help me with my problem. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call the function (in your case the one which generates random) that you want to run only once in a `useEffect` with empty dependency array and store the result in a state variable.

Sample:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(5);
  const [count2, setCount2] = useState(7);
  useEffect(() => {
    setCount(Math.random()*10)
    console.log('jjj')
  }, []);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>count: {count} and count2: {count2}</h2>
      <button onClick={()=>setCount2(count2+1)}>Count2+</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here count would only change once.

Comment: Tried implementing your answer and got the TypeError: cannot read properties of undefined error. Maybe I implemented it wrongly. I updated the CodeSandbox with my new code.

Comment: problem is in this line `setResult(generateQuestions());`  You're not returning anything from `generateQuestions` `return` the results array from the function

Comment: same thing in `ShuffleAnswers` function